# Spark sql query execution time needs to be computed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I running a Hive SQL query in spark by creating a context. I would like to compare it's performance with hive ql execution time ,but how do I get the exact execution time of the query?

Thanks
Raja

Comment: Most of Spark DataFrame operations are lazy, so I think you are probably going call some action (i.e. `df.count`) in them in order to calculate times programatically. Alternatively, if only visual benchmarking is enough, you can use Spark UI. If you elaborate your question a bit more, you may receive a more adapted answer.

Comment: I am running a SQL query ( select * from a hive table) and I want to know how much time does it exactly takes for querying the data and retrieving it